# Angular ui bootstrap accordion "only open one at a time" not working

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have an accordion (expandable / collapsible) using [Angular UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which has three panels.
[image]

I don't want the user to be able to open multiple panels at a time. The documentation give this option

```
<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
```

With this in the controler

```
$scope.oneAtATime = true;
```

But I'm still able to open multiple panels at a time. What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use it like this

```
<accordion close-others = "true">

</accordion>
```

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A7nTQ9aKsDS5FqF7v5c7?p=preview)

If these changes are not giving you expected results, then something else is not correct in your program, check the dependencies and create a plunker and post the link

Comment: This is not working. Dependencies are ok. I'll try to find out what's wrong outside accordion.

Comment: can you post more code? without that its difficult to tell what could be wrong/.. make a plunker if you can

Comment: The problem was I had an ng-repeat on a parent wrapper div around the accordion. I moved this ng-repeat to the accordion-heading, as it should be, and the closing works like a charm now.

Comment: glad you figured it out, and thank you for telling what it was - always curious as to what happens... :)